# Why isn't lxd init working on new install of Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: lxc, lxd

I have a VPS at SSDNodes.  I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 on it, ran update, upgrade, autoremove and clean.
I then tried to configure lxd using the `lxd init`. The cursor moved to the next line and did nothing. It wasn't flashing, it just sat there.
After more than 10 minutes it still hadn't done anything.  I tried `lxc list` and got the same result.
I did a `which lxd` and got `/usr/bin/lxd`
I did a `lxd --version` and got `3.0.3`
I did a `which lxc` and got `/usr/bin/lxc`
I did a `lxc --version` and got `3.0.3`
So why aren't `lxd init` and `lxd list` working?

I also tried creating a container and got:

```
randall@server1:~$ lxc-create -n inglesnobrasil -t ubuntu
lxc-create: inglesnobrasil: parse.c: lxc_file_for_each_line_mmap: 100 No such file or directory - Failed to open file "/home/randall/.config/lxc/default.conf"
lxc-create: inglesnobrasil: utils.c: get_template_path: 918 No such file or directory - bad template: ubuntu
lxc-create: inglesnobrasil: lxccontainer.c: do_lxcapi_create: 1786 Unknown template "ubuntu"
lxc-create: inglesnobrasil: tools/lxc_create.c: main: 327 Failed to create container inglesnobrasil
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using LXD from snaps? As per https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/migrate-from-ppa-to-snap/816

Run `snap install lxd` and then `lxd.migrate`

It will move all your data and then remove the old packages (deb) from your system.

I did that recently on my latest server install (from my history):
   10  sudo snap install lxd
   11  sudo /snap/bin/lxd.migrate
   12  /snap/bin/lxd init
   13  lxc list